# Pourquoi utiliser « elle » après « la France » ?

Tags: grammaire, sujet, emphase

J'ai remarqué que Hollande utilisait beaucoup cette construction:

> La France, elle a toujours (etc.)

quand il utilise la France en début de phrase, dans le moments les plus formels, et plus du tout dans les fins de discours (par exemple quand il donne des détails plus techniques)

À mon oreille ça sonne comme ceci:

> Maman, elle va revenir demain.

qu'une mère pourrait dire en parlant d'elle même à son enfant qui est en train d'apprendre le langage.

Quelle est cette construction ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cette construction est utilisée pour mettre en relief ou souligner le nom «La France». Cela peut peut-être se ressembler à une apposition.

*Exemple:* Moi, je l’ai fait sans l’aide de l’ordinateur.

Ici, on souligne le pronom personnel, pour insister ou montrer que c’est «moi» qui a fait l’action.

Dans votre exemple

> La France, elle a toujours...

un pronom est utilisé pour souligner «la France».
Il est possible que cette construction soit utilisée pour gagner du temps en pensant quoi dire après.

Additionnellement,

> Maman, elle va revenir demain.

est une phrase correcte.

Comparez

> Maman va revenir demain.

et

> Maman, elle va revenir demain.

Ne vous sentez pas que dans la deuxième phrase le nom «maman» est plus valorisé ou souligné?

Comment: Aussi [ici](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie8/elle).